# rmarkdown: recursive chunk evaluation?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to have a string produced by an `R` chunk in an `rmarkdown` document to be re-evaluated - is that possible? For demonstration purposes consider the following document:

````
---
params:
  B: 'test'
---

```{r simple, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
write(params[['B']], file = "")
```

```{r recursive-evaluation-questionmark, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
write(
  "How to get \"params[['B']]\" evaluated here? This \"`r params[['B']]`\" is
    expected to be \"test\" ...",
  file = "")
```
````

Currently this produces the following when knitted:

```
test

How to get “params[[‘B’]]” evaluated here? This “r params[['B']]” is expected to be “test” …
```

but I want:

```
test

How to get “params[[‘B’]]” evaluated here? This “test” is expected to be “test” …
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get `knitr` to treat R code as text, but you can solve the problem using pure R code.  I'd also recommend using `cat()` instead of `write()`.  For your example,

```
write(
  paste0("How to get \"params[['B']]\" evaluated here? This \"", params[['B']], "\" is
  expected to be \"test\" ..."),
 file = "")
```

or the simpler

```
cat("How to get \"params[['B']]\" evaluated here? This \"", params[['B']], "\" is
  expected to be \"test\" ...", sep = "")
```

For more complicated macro-like substitutions, you may want to use the `sub()` or `gsub()` functions, e.g.

```
msg <- "How to get \"params[['B']]\" evaluated here? This \"%param%\" is
  expected to be \"test\" ..."
cat(sub("%param%", params[['B']], msg))
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I actually had a similar solution using `brew` set up, but that get's really messy quickly ... envision e.g. a case where printing `params[['B']]` is supposed to be conditional on `params[['A']]` ...

Comment: Since this is all being done in R code, you can use conditionals.  Remember that `if` can be used inline, e.g. `cat(sub("%param%", if (params[["A"]]) params[['B']] else "something else", msg))`